# Debian Jessie NS LOOKUP ip

Tags: domain-name-system, debian, nslookup

When i use command

```
nslookup 192.168.1.1 or (my real ip address)
```

back this:

```
1.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa   name = 1.1.168.192-my-net.net
```

I want to change name with my website example

```
1.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa    name = www.example.com
```

How to do this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`in-addr.arpa` is special domain name to get full qualified domain name of host from ip address. This is called 
 [reverse DNS lookup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_DNS_lookup).

You need to assign new DNS zone `1.168.192.in-addr.arpa` on your DNS server. Then you can add PTR record `1  PTR  full.your.host.name` in file of this zone.

You can see an example of such zone at  https://serverfault.com/questions/462474/how-do-i-set-up-a-reverse-zone-file

Also another way exists. Add string `192.168.1.1 full.your.host.name` to file `/etc/hosts` on your workstation.

Comment: i have add  my.real.ip.addr mydomain.com, in /etc/hosts but name it's not change for the ip address

Comment: Your ip address isn't real, add it as real with same hostname.

Comment: The ip address in post (192.168.1.1) it's example, not ip address who i use. I have bind9 dns server. Do you tell me particularly how to add ptr record?  Thank you!

Comment: I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to do that? If it is for a `192.168.x.y` it means a private IP on your network so it will depend on how you run your local recursive nameservers (and you will need to do basically what is in Mikhail answer).

If it is for a public IP (what you call the real ip ?) you will need to ask the owner of the IP block in which your IP is, so that he will either, do the reverse resolution for you, or delegate this handling to your nameservers if you have more than one IP address from them and you want to handle the reverse resolution yourself. Hard to help you more without knowing the real IP we are speaking about.

Comment: I want to do this, because this host my.real.ip.my-net.net it's confuse my mail server.