# reverse file not working . gives error message "bad dotted quad"

Tags: reverse-dns

here is my zone file

```
$TTL 86400
@       IN SOA  master.git-gotech.net. root.git-gotech.net (
                                        0       ; serial
                                        3600    ; refresh
                                        1800    ; retry
                                        604800  ; expire
                                        86400 ) ; minimum

@      IN  NS     master.git-gotech.net.
@      IN  A      10.1.10.189
189    IN  A      master.git-gotech.net.
159    IN  A      jessica-vm1.git-gotech.net.
```

Comment: check how your zone file compare to [this example](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/4/html/reference_guide/s2-bind-configuration-zone-reverse) - or even [this answer in serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/462474/how-do-i-set-up-a-reverse-zone-file)

Answer (score 2):

If this is supposed to be a reverse zone file (for zone `10.1.10.in-addr.arpa.`) then the last two lines should be IN PTR records, instead of IN A:

```
189    IN  PTR      master.git-gotech.net.
159    IN  PTR      jessica-vm1.git-gotech.net.
```

That should fix the error message.

Also, although the record

```
@      IN  A      10.1.10.189
```

would be syntactically valid, it should be omitted because it's completely useless in a reverse zone.

Comment: And the line `@      IN  A      10.1.10.189` should be completely omitted as well.

Comment: @HBrujin Thanks, edited.

Answer (score -1):

An A record maps a domain name to the IP address (Version 4) of the computer hosting the domain. An A record uses a domain name to find the IP address of a computer connected to the internet, Some samples are given below.

```
ns1    IN  A      192.168.0.1
www    IN  A      192.168.0.2
bill   IN  A      192.168.0.3
fred   IN  A      192.168.0.4
```

I can see you are using domain name for A records.

Comment: Although that is typically correct, in a reverse zone one expects PTR and FQDN's and not A records.